# KnockoutJS rendering external Templates dynamically

Tags: knockout.js, template-engine

I am developing SPA in KnockoutJS, and facing an issue in rendering external templates in KnockoutJS.

I am using External Template Engine by Jim Cowart.
https://github.com/ifandelse/Knockout.js-External-Template-Engine

This binding :

`<div data-bind='template: {name: 'template1', templateUrl:"/dynamicviewtemplate"}'></div>`

works. While this one :

```
<div data-bind='template: {name: templateName, templateUrl:"/dynamicviewtemplate"}'></div>
```

does not work.

Template does not load based on the observable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `template` binding does not automatically unwrap the `name` field. You can fix this by specifying your binding like:

```
data-bind='template: {name: templateName(), templateUrl:"/dynamicviewtemplate"}'
```